# Like term reduction

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In finding the derivative of $f(x) = 4x - x^2$ we first find the difference of the numerator $f(x + h) - f(x)$.  Therefore we have $f(x + h) = 4(x + h) - (x + h)^2 = 4x + 4h - x^2 - 2xh - h^2$ minus $f(x) = 4x - x^2$.  This leads to entire expression in the numerator being:

$$4x + 4h - x^2 -2xh -h^2 - (4x - x^2) $$

My book reduces this to $4h - 2xh - h^2$.  Now I understand how the $4x$ and the $-4x$ cancel.  But isn't $-x^2 - x^2 = 2x^2$?  How did they eliminate this term in the reduction?  If I plug in numbers (e.g. $x= 2 h = 3$) the reduction is not equal to the original equation.

In my experience I am wrong more than any math book so how am I going astray here?  Am I missing a sign somewhere?

Comment: Hint: you lost a minus and have $ -x^2 - (-x^2)$, for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing that $- (-x^2) = +x^2$

Comment: I know you are right but I am struggling to isolate the underlying rule.  So I was thinking that in eliminating 4x the last part became $h^2 - x^2$.  In reality the operator is *not* removed but just the term?  Thus after removal it is $h^2 - -x^2$?  And this is the case in all such operations?

Comment: The last term is $- (4x - x^2)$ which is shorthand for $-1 (4x - x^2)$. Now, multiply throughout and remove the brackets to get $-4x + x^2$. I hope that helps.

Comment: Ok, thanks to everyone.  Obviously I have some work to do.